# How to show script having display none

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am inspecting this [page](https://www.ifrs.org/use-around-the-world/use-of-ifrs-standards-by-jurisdiction/) :

```
<script>
        var countries_datasource = '6ca8faa0-a908-4b08-a5b3-df91e3ef5af8';
</script>
```

When checking the CSS styles, I found this :

```
script {
    display: none;
}
```

[image]

How can I display the content of the script ?

Comment: It's not usually considered normal/desirable to display a script tag, but if you really want to, you could change the CSS to `display:block;`. Depending on the content you might also want to add `white-space:pre;`, if you want it to handle carriage returns and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `textContent`.

```
var script = ... //e.g. document.querySelector('script') for first script element
var content = script.textContent;
```

```js
const script = document.querySelector('#myScript'),
      content = script.textContent;
console.log(content);
```

```html
<script id="myScript">
        var countries_datasource = '6ca8faa0-a908-4b08-a5b3-df91e3ef5af8';
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `display: block` to the script tag.

```html
<script style="display: block">
  console.log("Hello World!")
</script>
```

That style

```
script {
  display: none;
}
```

is automatically set be the browser FYI. Chrome writes `user agent stylesheet` as the source, with `user agent` referring to the browser.

Comment: Where I can find the script after adding style="display: block" ?

Comment: Just above the map or under `"Click here to view our disclaimer."`

Comment: I get var countries_datasource = '6ca8faa0-a908-4b08-a5b3-df91e3ef5af8';
I want the code behind.

Comment: That is not what you asked in your question. Also that is the whole code. At least one of us is confused

Answer (score 1):

You can add style="display: block" to script tag

```
<script style="display: block">
```

this will work because a thing called specificity.
Specificity determines when one style overrides another. Generally, inline styles have a higher specificity, hence it will override the

```
display: none;
```

applied above.

you can read more about specificity here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp